# Kafka producer unable to produce after one broker dies in a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Thank you, everyone for all your assistance, my project is successfully integrated with Kafka.While testing i came with a issue for which i need a little assistance. my producer and consumer both were pointing to Kafka broker say KB-1. i have cluster of brokers with replication factor 1.KB-1 dies due to some internal reason so we switched the IP's of our producer and consumer to another broker of same cluster KB-2. It was effective to consume all data and process the necessary alerts necessary,but when i tried to produce the data through producer with KB-2 IP in bootstrap server it failed  to produce giving the  following error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
please also explain single point failure if possible.
thank you for the help.

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using ? Post your kafka.properties configuration.

Comment: Kafka version :0.10
properties:
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "KB-2");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 3);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);  
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");